# How to install a certificate along with a SharePoint WebPart?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, ssl-certificate

I created a SharePoint WebPart, that needs a X509 certificate to work properly. I deploy the WebPart using a WSP solution file.

Is there any way to configure the WSP file to automatically install the certificate on the server during deployment?

Answer (score 2):

in general, when you have to do something special on the host computer, the best place is in a feature receiver, and within the FeatureInstalled event. This event is fired on all servers in the farm.

you should try using this way